# Sowing down a for loop in a text file

Tags: c#, for-loop, timer

I have a loop which runs and writes to a text file.

My only problem is when i put in my timer for each loop to take 5 seconds,
it instead loops 5 seconds before writing.

Where do i need to put my timer for it work correctly?

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Timothy\Desktop\myTextFile.txt", true))
        {

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i < 100)
                {

                    writer.WriteLine("WELCOME????");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All DONE");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Finished Writing");
            Console.ReadLine();
            writer.Close();
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "correctly"? You haven't told us why you are adding a timer in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the loop:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            if (i < 100)
            {

                writer.WriteLine("WELCOME????");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("All DONE");
            }
        }
```

Also, since you check for i to be smaller than 100 in the loop definition (on the last run, i will be 99), 'ALL DONE' will never be displayed. What you need is:

```
if (i < 99)
```